# Почему я не могу изменить стили элемента по их классу?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему по id могу изменять свойства элемента, а по классу - нет?

```js
function show(){
  document.getElementById('idsquare').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementsByClassName('square').style.display = "none";
  }
```

```css
.square, #idsquare{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  }
  
.square{
  background-color: #FF6699
}

#idsquare {
  background-color: #FF0099
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="show()">Нажми меня!</a>
<div class="square"></div>
<div id="idsquare"></div>
```

Comment: Потому что там массив элементов `document.getElementsByClassName('square')`, а не один элемент как `document.getElementById('idsquare')`.

Comment: Вон, в ответе, доступ к первому элементу показали. Аж два раза :)

Comment: @Visman спасибо)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это потому, что  ID может быть только один у элемента и в единственном экземпляре на всей странице , а классов одинаковым множество, или надо прописать индекс класса, как я сделал или прокручивать все классы в цикле

```js
function show(){
  document.getElementById('idsquare').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementsByClassName('square')[0].style.display = "none";
  }
```

```css
.square, #idsquare{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  }
  
.square{
  background-color: #FF6699
}

#idsquare {
  background-color: #FF0099
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="show()">Нажми меня!</a>
<div class="square"></div>
<div id="idsquare"></div>
```

Comment: Ого! Спасибо, приму как ответ....когда смогу)

Comment: всегда пожалуйста)))

Comment: А есть ли способ в HTML задать свои индексы(ключи)?

Comment: Если честно не понял о чем вы? Что вы имеете ввиду под словом индексы и ключи?

Answer (score 3):

Если элемент с классом `square` один на странице - то вам нужно брать нулевой элемент, т.е.

```
function show(){
  document.getElementById('idsquare').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementsByClassName('square')[0].style.display = "none";
  }
```

А вообще, лучше не изобретать велосипеды, а сделать на `jQuery`, в котором есть свои функции `show` и `hide`. И почему-то ваша функция `show` не показывает элементы, а призвана их прятать. В связи с этим, рекомендую к прочтению: [Как не надо писать код](https://learn.javascript.ru/write-unmain-code)
**UPD**
Если у вас будет много элементов с классом `square` - ваш код сработает только для самого первого. Чтобы спрятать все элементы с таким классом, вам поможет такой код:

```
$('.square').hide();
```

Comment: Читала) мне просто надо было на простейшем примере продемонстрировать работу куска кода из реального проекта (где как раз показывает объекты кнопка, а не скрывает), накидала простейший образец.