# Кнопка Закрытия блока работает только на одной картинке

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ребят, есть галерея миниатюрами при клике на миниатюру появляется блок с описанием миниатюры, и сверху находится кнопка(Х)-для того чтобы закрыть этот блок. Проблема в том , что он работает только с самой первой картинкой. Как сделать чтобы он работал со всеми картинками. [КОД](https://jsfiddle.net/h8wojdtq/1/)-зайдите на второй там Collection чтобы увидеть галерею.

CSS-сама кнопка

```
#closeButton{
    width:16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-image: url("http://cbmedia3.contobox.com/cbox_themes_v3/marks_fall_footwear_q4_2017/images/demoCloseBtn.png?ac=1506976312");
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 14px;
}
```

HTML - код нескольких

```
<div class="col-pr col-pr-1" data-pos="1">
  <div class='modal-for-photo' id="nameToClose">
    <div class='modal-background'></div>
      <div class='modal-body'>
       <span id="closeButton"></span>
        <p>It's Me! Mario!</p>
        </div>
         </div>
            </div>

<div class="col-pr col-pr-2" data-pos="2">
   <div class='modal-for-photo' id="nameToClose">
    <div class='modal-background'></div>
      <div class='modal-body'>
        <span id="closeButton"></span>
          <p>It's Me! Mario! #2</p>
          </div>
  </div>
```

Js

```
document.getElementById('closeButton').addEventListener('click',function () {
    document.getElementById('nameToClose').style.display = 'none';
});
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему я не могу изменить стили элемента по их классу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729332/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%83)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аттрибут id желательно делать уникальным. 
В Вашем случае именно поэтому не отработал js, так как getElementById() работает с первым найденным элементом. 
Для решения можно попробовать следующую реализацию (я заменяю id на class).

CSS:

```
.closeButton{
    width:16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-image: url("http://cbmedia3.contobox.com/cbox_themes_v3/marks_fall_footwear_q4_2017/images/demoCloseBtn.png?ac=1506976312");
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 14px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-pr col-pr-1" data-pos="1">
  <div class='modal-for-photo nameToClose'>
    <div class='modal-background'></div>
      <div class='modal-body'>
       <span class="closeButton"></span>
        <p>It's Me! Mario!</p>
        </div>
         </div>
            </div>

<div class="col-pr col-pr-2" data-pos="2">
   <div class='modal-for-photo nameToClose'>
    <div class='modal-background'></div>
      <div class='modal-body'>
        <span class="closeButton"></span>
          <p>It's Me! Mario! #2</p>
          </div>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('closeButton');

[].forEach.call(buttons,function(el){
    el.addEventListener('click', function () {
        el.closest('.nameToClose').style.display = 'none';
    });
});
```

Comment: я пробовал так сделать , не вышло, даже на второй таб не заходит при этой реализации

Comment: выводит вот такую ошибку ==> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).addEventListener is not a function
    at index.html?_ijt=18nl3eoe9htjsfiuqviogrqjfo:1242
(anonymous) @ index.html?_ijt=18nl3eoe9htjsfiuqviogrqjfo:1242

Comment: Document.getElementsByClassName() - Возвращает массивоподобный (итерируемый) объект всех дочерних элементов, соответствуюих всем из указанных имен классов. Обратить внимание на "итерируемый".

Comment: Поправил - теперь работает

Comment: Обратите внимание, что CSS тоже нужно изменить
Вместо #closeButton стало .closeButton

Comment: Антон, получилось?

Comment: @SmolinPavel да, работает, но консоль ругается и выдает такую ошибку index.html?_ijt=18nl3eoe9htjsfiuqviogrqjfo:1252 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.show_modal (index.html?_ijt=18nl3eoe9htjsfiuqviogrqjfo:1252)

Comment: @Anton у меня чистая консоль и все работает.

Comment: @SmolinPavel у меня он ругается на это строку js   var show_modal = function(event){
        var photo_elem = event.target.getElementsByClassName('modal-for-photo')[0];
        photo_elem.style.display = 'block';
    };

Comment: @SmolinPavel ошибки появляется тогда, когда кликаешь на Close

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что может быть проблема с тем, что у Вас несколько элементов имеют одинаковый идентификатор nameToClose.

Comment: так оно и есть id у всех одинаковый и поэтому не получается