# appendChild не работает

Tags: javascript, html5, append

Мне нужно добавить *`div, p или hr`* (любой элемент) после каждого `p`, но есть некоторые проблемы.

У меня есть код `JS`, и я получаю ошибку **`appendChild is not a function`**.

В чем проблема?

```js
var parent = document.getElementsByTagName("article")[0];
var paragraph = parent.getElementsByTagName("p");
var newElement = document.createElement("hr");
paragraph.appendChild(newElement);
```

```html
<article>
  <div>div with text</div>
  <p>paragraph with text</p>
</article>
```

Comment: `var paragraph = parent.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729332/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%83/729336#729336

Answer (score -2):

Ошибка у вас возникает, из-за того, что у вас в переменной `paragraph` находиться не сам элемент, а коллекция - `HTMLCollection`. Даже если у вас один элемент на странице с таким тегом, то все равно вернется коллекция. Если не ошибаюсь, то единственным исключением является [document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

В примере ниже видно, что ваш элемент храниться под числовым индексом: `0`.
По этому вам нужно переменной paragraph присвоить значение: `parent.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];`, как вам предложил это сделать [Igor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176262/igor) в комментариях.

```js
var parent = document.getElementsByTagName("article")[0];
var paragraph = parent.getElementsByTagName("p");
console.log(paragraph);
```

```html
<article>
  <div>div with text</div>
  <p>paragraph with text</p>
</article>
```

**Element.getElementsByTagName()**

`Element.getElementsByTagName()` метод возвращает живую коллекцию элементов [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) , учитывая [имя тэга](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.tagName). Поиск осуществляется в поддереве указанного элемента, в результат поиска не попадает сам элемент, в поддереве которого осуществлялся поиск. Возвращает живой список, который автоматически обновляется при изменении DOM. Поэтому не нужно вызывать метод `Element.getElementsByTagName()` несколько раз с одними и теми же аргументами, содержимое списка обновляется автоматически.

При вызове на HTML-элементе в HTML-документе метод  `getElementsByTagName` переводит аргумент по которому осуществляется поиск (имя тега) в нижний регистр до того как начать поиск. Это нежелательно, когда необходимо использовать метод для поиска SVG элементов, где в наименовании тега может использоваться верблюжья (camel-cased) нотация. В этом случае правильно использовать метод [Element.getElementsByTagNameNS()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagNameNS).

`Element.getElementsByTagName` похож на [Document.getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName), за исключением того, что поиск осуществляется среди потомков конкретного элемента, а не во всём HTML-документе.

Источник: [Element.getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName).